# How to set local value in Edittext with first letter Capital in Android?

Tags: java, android

i have the value like **WORK** but i want to set this to edit text like **Work**. Can anybody help me out?

Comment: check my updated ans

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/txtCapitalize"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:inputType="textCapSentences" />

EditText txtCapitalize = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txtCapitalize);
    txtCapitalize.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT | InputType.TYPE_TEXT_FLAG_CAP_WORDS);
```

or android:inputType="textCapSentences" will only work If your device keyboard Auto Capitalize Setting enabled.

Comment: I have tried  android:inputType="textCapSentences" in XML but it is still showing WORK only.

Answer (score 1):

Configure your `EditText` with `android:textAllCaps="false"`.
Then programatically modify your variable as you want using **String** function as [`toLowerCase`](https://www.javatpoint.com/java-string-tolowercase) (for the all string) and [`toUpperCase`](https://www.javatpoint.com/java-string-touppercase)(the first letter).

Answer (score 1):

```
String str = yourEditText.getText().toString();
str = str.toUpperCase().charAt(0) + str.substring(1);
```